# Return type in lambda expression, Reduce function

Tags: java, lambda, stream, reduce

in static method I've implemented inner class:

```
 class Inner implements  Comparable<Inner>
    {
        Integer v;
        String s;

        public Inner(Integer a, String st) {v = a; s= st; }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Inner o) {
            int result = Integer.compare(this.v,o.v);

            if (result == 0)
                return (String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(this.s,o.s));
        else
            return result;
        }
    }
```

It's purpose's to hold String and Integer values. Aditionally class implements Comparable interface, so that it's sortable

Main container for Inner's class instances is *ArrayList*

```
ArrayList<Inner> cont = new ArrayList<>();
```

After filling dynamic array I want to sort it and next concat String values, all of this using Streams.

```
String  res =  cont.stream().sorted(Inner::compareTo).reduce(" ",(String r, Inner e)->{return r+=e.s+" ";});
```

Unfortunately, compilator sends me error:

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to Inner
```

Is any way to solve it, still usings Streams?

Regards

Comment: *"in static method I've implemented inner class"* --- What static method? *Inner* classes are not inside methods, *local* and *anonymous* classes are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take the `s` of `Inner` using `.map()` before reduce. And it's better to use  `Collectors.joining` to join the string with delimiter

```
cont.stream().sorted(Inner::compareTo).map(e -> e.s).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```